# Resharper doesn't play well with XAML?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, xaml, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I've been noticing a pattern with ReSharper (both 4.5 and 5).

Very often (almost always) when I have solution-wide analysis turned on, and WPF code in my solution, ReSharper will mark a number of the .xaml.cs files as being broken.

When I navigate to the file, sometimes it magically updates and displays no errors, and other times I have to open other files that are not being correctly read and close them again to force resharper to correctly analyze them.

I assume it has something to do with the temporary .cs code that is generated with XAML, but does anyone know *why* this is actually happening, and if there is a work around?  Should I just file a bug report with JetBrains?  Does anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper 6.0 provides much improved XAML support.

Comment: Nice, I'll have to check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: I would say there are still some serious problems with ReSharper 6.0 and XAML parsing. Especially with the color identifiers turned on. After about 20 minutes Visual Studio just sloowwwss to a crawwwwllll.

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper 7.1](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/11/resharper-71-is-available/) seems to have improved on XAML support, and solve the issues still present in 6.0

> XAML support is now considerably smoother in terms of code completion, typing assistance, naming style control, and code generation

See "[XAML Support Refresh in ReSharper 7.1](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/10/resharper-71-xaml-support-refresh/)"